# Can't access collections and data on mongo though userAdmin

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication

I am trying to set security settings to my mongo instance.
It's on a single remote Linux server.
I followed the tutorial of mongo documentation.
That's the steps actions I have executed:

```
// running mongod with auth 
mongod --auth --config /path-to-conf-file
// connect to mongo with local host exception
mongo
// creating user admin
use admin
db.createUser({
    user:"myadmin",
    pwd:"1234",
    roles: [
        "userAdminAnyDatabase"
    ]})
// logging in with user admin
mongo -u myadmin -p 1234 --authenticationDatabase     admin
```

I get the warning: 'not authorized on admin to execute command {getLog: "start up warnings"}'
I am able to create users and 'show dbs' but can't 'show collections'

I get the other error : 'not authorized for query on admin.system.namespaces'

So I think the user was created not as admin. What can I do in order to log in and be able to make query operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `myadmin` user has [`userAdminAnyDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdminAnyDatabase) privileges. This means the user can grant any privileges to any user in any database, but it doesn't give the user permissions to do non-user management operations. The solution is to use the `myadmin` user's user administration privileges to grant itself more privileges. For query operations on any database, grant the [`readWriteAnyDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWriteAnyDatabase) role. There's lots of [built-in roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) to choose from.